# How do you rate-limit API requests across files? [nodejs]

Tags: node.js, rate-limiting

I'm trying to use a the [bottleneck module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck#debugging-your-application) but this question applies to any rate-limiting module.

You can create a limiter like so

```
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  minTime: 333
});
```

But what if I need to use the same limiter in multiple files? Would I create the limiter again or do I pass it around?

Example file:

```
// Call to limit

module.exports = axios.get('some-endpoint').then(res => return res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what your use case is.

Let's say you are using `limiter` to throttle your requests to some third-party API, and you want to make sure you only make 3 requests per second, and you make them from multiple modules. In this case, yes, you need to pass that limiter around and use it in multiple modules.

A much better design in this case would be to make sure *only one module* calls the API, and that one module has the limiter. For example:

```
// api.js
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
    minTime: 333
});

module.exports = {
    makeRequest: limiter.wrap(options => {
        // interact with API and return response
    });
};
```

And then, each of your other modules just use your internal API:

```
// some-other-module.js
const api = require('./api');

module.exports = {
    createCustomer: (options) => {
        return api.makeRequest({ ... });
    }
};
```

This way the limiter only exists in one place in your application, but is used by all modules that interact with that API.

(If you interact with multiple vendors, then of course, it would make sense to have a different limiter with different settings per vendor.)

Comment: This was an extremely well written and helpful answer, thank you!